# showing unknown symbols while adding breakpoint in vs2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

[image: SS after adding BreakPoint]

While adding breakpoint. This line look as display in screenshot.
But breakpoints works normally fine. How can I remove this question marks ?

Comment: Need to know more about your setup. Your Windows locale? Whether the source files are ASCII or UTF-8? Or UTF-16? Or Shift-JIS? if you are using some special font for your IDE?

Comment: @YePhlcK Actually I am not aware of it. That how can i check  Windows locale. I am using other versions too on my same machine like vs2010 and vs2015. All are working fine. I am using default setting of VS 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Visual Studio SP1 will solve this problem. It's a bug, and it appears on older version of VS.
Download link is here -> [Visual studio 2005 sp1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5553)